# c# wpf access object defined in references

Tags: c#, wpf

A simple scenario to show my question:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key=myTemplate>
        <Grid x:Name="myGrid">
            <TextBox x:Name="myTextbox" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
<Window.Resources>

<Window>
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <ContentControl x:Name="myContent" Source="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How do I access TextBox 'myTextbox' from C# code?

Comment: If you have to find using VisualTreeHelper. Check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx

Comment: `ContentControl` has no `Source` property. The name of template `x:Key` is without quotes.

Comment: @user3684516, why do you need Template here? why not put "myGrid" directly into "mainGrid", without any ContentControl?

Comment: *"How do I access TextBox 'myTextbox' from C# code?:"* -- you don't. What do you want to *do* with that textbox in your codebehind? Tell us, and we can help you do it in a way that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method
frameworktemplate.FindName where framework element is your data template